# Need support with formatting x-axis group labels to not overlap

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot, graphing

I have created a notched boxplot of some data in R using the ggplot2 package. I have a problem that the x-axis element text makes the labels of my groups overlap, which I do not want.

I also do not want to rotate the labels. Preferably, I would like each label to be written horizontally but continued on a 'separate' line. So that the two words of the (e.g.) label Carboniferous Lst. appears as two words with the second word 'Limestone' written horizontally below Carboniferous. I cannot reduce font size, as it will then be too difficult to read.

Does anyone know whether there is a command in R's ggplot that takes care of this?

Many, many thanks

Damiano

PS: My current code is:

```
box <- ggplot(AquiProps, aes(Geology, logTRANS))

box + geom_boxplot(notch = TRUE) 
    + labs(x = "", y = "Mean log Transmissivity(m2/d)") 
    + theme(axis.title = element_text(face = "bold", size = "12", color = "black"),
            axis.text = element_text(size = 10, face = "bold", color = "black"),
            axis.title.y = element_text(vjust = 1), 
            axis.title.x = element_text(vjust = 0.005))
```

I imagine I need to change something in the axis.title.x=element_text command?!?!

Comment: Is `AquiProps` a built-in dataset in R? If not, then your code doesn't help without the data. If it is built-in, then what package?

Answer (score 4):

Like this?

[image]

```
# create example
set.seed(1)
names <- paste("Carboniferous Species:",1:8)
df <- data.frame(names=rep(names,each=100),values=rnorm(800))

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df,aes(x=names,y=values))+
  geom_boxplot(notch=TRUE)+
  scale_x_discrete(labels=gsub("(Carboniferous)","\\1\n",unique(df$names)))+
  theme(axis.title = element_text(face = "bold", size = "12", color = "black"),
        axis.text = element_text(size = 10, face = "bold", color = "black"),
        axis.title.y = element_text(vjust = 1), 
        axis.title.x = element_text(vjust = 0.005))
```

The code above inserts line breaks into the axis labels using `scale_x_discrete(labels=...)`.

You could also insert the line breaks directly into your data, using e.g.:

```
df$names <- gsub("(Carboniferous)","\\1\n",df$names)
```

Then your code as written would generate the same plot above.

Answer (score 0):

It's an old question but since [`ggplot` 3.3.0](https://www.tidyverse.org/blog/2020/03/ggplot2-3-3-0/), it's easy solve.

You can use the argument `guide = guide_axis(n.dodge = 2)` inside`scale_x_discrete`.

```
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(1)
names <- paste("Carboniferous Species:",1:8)
df <- data.frame(names=rep(names,each=100),values=rnorm(800))

ggplot(df,aes(x=names,y=values))+
  geom_boxplot(notch=TRUE)+
  scale_x_discrete(guide = guide_axis(n.dodge = 2)) +
  theme(axis.title = element_text(face = "bold",
                                  size = "12",
                                  color = "black"),
        axis.text = element_text(size = 10,
                                 face = "bold",
                                 color = "black"),
        axis.title.y = element_text(vjust = 1), 
        axis.title.x = element_text(vjust = 0.005))
```

Result: 
[image]